# Error plotting SVM classification results for the spam dataset

Tags: r, dataset, runtime-error, svm, kernlab

I am having problem with plotting results of `SVM` classification for the spam dataset from `kernlab` package..

**Code**:

```
require(kernlab)

data(spam)

index <- sample(1:dim(spam)[1])
spamtrain <- spam[index[1:floor(dim(spam)[1]/2)], ]
spamtest <- spam[index[((ceiling(dim(spam)[1]/2)) + 1):dim(spam)[1]], ]

filter <- ksvm(type~.,data=spamtrain,kernel="rbfdot",kpar=list(sigma=0.05),C=5,cross=3)

plot(filter, data=spamtrain)
```

**Error:**

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(expand.grid(lis), , labels(terms(x))) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Comment: Don't you mean `plot(filter)` ?

Comment: Yes, it should be `plot(filter, data=spamtrain)` - I made a typo in the question. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, `plot.ksvm` (which is called when you use `plot` on a `ksvm` object) can only plot objects with two features, i.e., the data matrix can only have two columns.  Unfortunately, this is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation, and I just spent a couple of hours trying to understand what was going wrong.  I don't know if this is planned to be fixed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `plot` from package `kernlab` so that it is supporting format of `ksvm` objects. `kernlab::plot(object, data=NULL, grid = 50, slice = list())`

More info in doc on kernab plot here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/kernlab.pdf